# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.RescorerQuery

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using `spring-data-elasticsearch:4.3.2` and `spring-boot-starter:2.6.4`, I can navigate to the `RescorerQuery` class in Intellij but upon bootstrapping, it logs this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/RescorerQuery
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.RescorerQuery
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

**Update**: Turns out it is due to version compatibility. If I change `spring-boot-starter` to version `2.5.5` it works perfectly. However `RescorerQuery` is not recommended since it will make the query time a lot longer.

Comment: what do you mean with "on bootstrapping"? How do you start the application? Can you share the maven/gradle configuration or how you define the dependencies?

Comment: I use Intellij IDE to start the application. I can make it works now but I will not use `RescorerQuery` since it's too slow.